# System of nonlinear ODEs remains in positive cone

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

Given a system of three first order nonlinear ODEs

$
 \begin{align*}
   x_1' &= f(x_1,x_2,x_3) \\
   x_2' &= g(x_1,x_2,x_3) \\
   x_3' &= h(x_1,x_2,x_3),
 \end{align*} 
$

I'm hoping to be able to show that, given a positive initial condition and, for simplicity, $x_1 = 0$, that $x_2$ and $x_3$ remain in the positive cone. Is there a method commonly used for this? I'm just looking for a starting point.

Comment: Check where vector field points along the boundary of $\mathbb{R}^3_{+}$. For example, a normal vector that points to the inward of $\mathbb{R}^3_{+}$ along $x_3 = 0$ is $(0, 0, 1)$; if a vector field points everywhere to the inward, then $\langle (f(x_1, x_2, 0), g(x_1, x_2, 0), h(x_1, x_2, 0)), (0, 0, 1) \rangle = h(x_1, x_2, 0)$ should be positive.